# Running a python code with multiple aws ec2 server

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My server is not enough for my script so I want to do that code on 20 aws ec2 free server. Also I can do it with bash so parallel-ssh module seems okay but I can't use .pem auth with parallel-ssh module.

Example of what I want to do:

```
from some_module import multiple_server_connect

hosts = ["45.67.89.10", "123.45.67.89", "12.34.56.78"]

for i in range(150):
    multiple_server_connect(hosts[0], pem_file="Kali.pem", method=ssh, execute=do_something(i))
    multiple_server_connect(hosts[1], pem_file="Kali.pem", method=ssh, execute=do_something1(i))
    multiple_server_connect(hosts[2], pem_file="Kali.pem", method=ssh, execute=do_something2(i))
```

How to do that?

Comment: If you want to run script on multiple EC2 instance Aws auto scale is a good solution,

Comment: Be aware of [SSM Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html) which can run a specific script on multiple EC2 instances, determined by tags or other selection criteria.